# Live Preview not working in some sections

Tags: live-preview

Live preview works in some sections, but not ones that use routes and have "entries in this section have their own urls" deselected.

Is this expected behaviour?

Is there any way to use live preview on these sections?

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior.  Live Preview is meant to show you what that entry will look like on the front-end of your site with the template specified in that section's setting.

If that entry doesn't have a URL as defined in the section settings, then there is nothing to preview.

Comment: Ok, so you can't use it when your entries use routes for display on the front end. Big limitation.